# Stylus linter (stylint) for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, stylus

Repository [Stylint](https://github.com/SimenB/stylint) indicates that linter works in:

- Atom
- Sublime Text
- WebStorm / PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDEA
- Visual Studio Code

In Atom it works perfectly. From CLI too.

Link from repository to vscode extension: [Stylint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vtfn.stylint). Link from marketplace to [github repository](https://github.com/vtfn/vscode-stylint) - 404. Extension doesn't provide any description or commands (most likely it's removed or broken).

How do I lint stylus?

Comment: I just wrote an extension. It can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HaaLeo.vscode-stylint). The extension is not that extensive yet. However you could give it a try and maybe it even fits your use case?

Comment: Haven't used stylus for some time. You can put it as an answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Alex in the comments I add my comment here as answer:
There exists a **new** [Stylint Extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HaaLeo.vscode-stylint) you can use instead for linting stylus files in VS Code.